# Decorating an object's interface with additional behavior in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby object that dispatches events to a third-party service:

```
class Dispatcher
  def track_event(e)
    ThirdPartyService.track e.id, e.name, my_api_key
  end
end
```

The use of `ThirdPartyService` may raise errors (e.g. if no network connection is available). It's usually appropriate for consumers of `Dispatcher` to decide how to deal with these, rather than `Dispatcher` itself.

How could we decorate the use of `Dispatcher` in such a way that objects *appear* to be using a `Dispatcher`, but all exceptions are caught and logged instead? That is, I want to be able to write:

```
obj.track_event(...)
```

but have exceptions be caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughtbot has a great blog post on [different ways to implement decorators in Ruby](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in). This one ("Module + Extend + Super decorator") is especially succinct:

```
module ErrorLoggingMixin
  def track_event(event)
    super
  rescue ex
    Logger.warn(ex)
  end
end

obj = Dispatcher.new          # initialize a Dispatcher as usual
obj.extend(ErrorLoggingMixin) # extend it with the new behavior

obj.track_event(some_event)   # call its methods as usual
```

The blog post lists these pros and cons:

> The benefits of this implementation are:
>
> - it delegates through all decorators
> - it has all of the original interface because it is the original object
>
> The drawbacks of this implementation are:
>
> - can not use the same decorator more than once on the same object
>     *difficult to tell which decorator added the functionality

I recommend reading the rest of the post to see the other implementations and make the choice that best fits your needs.

Comment: This is a great strategy, and I'm mad I didn't think of it myself. +1!

Answer (score 1):

The closest idea I've got is to surround the usage of `track_event` in a method which provides a block that catches exceptions, like this:

```
module DispatcherHelper
  def self.dispatch(&block)
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.new
    begin
      yield dispatcher
    rescue NetworkError
      # ...
    rescue ThirdPartyError
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

so that we can then do:

```
DispatcherHelper.dispatch { |d| d.track_event(...) }
```

The other alternative I can see is to mimic the signature of `track_event`, so that you get:

```
module DispatcherHelper
  def self.track_event(e)
    begin
      Dispatcher.new.track_event(e)
    rescue NetworkError
      # ...
    rescue ThirdPartyError
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

but I'm less fond of that since it ties the signatures together.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Bang Method

There's more than one way to do this. One way to accomplish your goal would be a small refactoring to redefine the exception-raising method as a "cautionary" method, make it private, and use the "safer" bang-free method in the public interface. For example:

```
class Dispatcher
  def track_event(e)
    result = track_event! e rescue nil
    result ? result : 'Exception handled here.'
  end

  private

  def track_event! e
    ThirdPartyService.track e.id, e.name, my_api_key
  end
end
```

Using the refactored code would yield the following when an exception is raised by ThirdPartyService:

```
Dispatcher.new.track_event 1
#=> "Exception handled here."
```

There are certainly other ways to address this type of problem. A lot depends on what your code is trying to express. As a result, your mileage may vary.

Comment: The `track_event` method would need to invoke an exception logger which only exists in the context of the consumer, so this won't work. But it's a good starting point.